# subscribeNext not getting values in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate, reactive-cocoa

I have scenario where my app receives an application:openURL:sourceApplication call from an extension and I want to open a tab in my tabBar and once its fully loaded then sendNext to a signal that the tabBar will be listening to once its loaded.

so sequence of events would be something like:

1. AppDelegate receives an OpenURL call
2. AppDelegate requests tabBar to load/open a tab called RemindersViewController
3. RemindersViewController RACSubject called RemindersLoadedSignal which i send to it a next value of true once the view has complete loading and binding
4. AppDelegate listens to the RemindersLoadedSignal and when it receives next from it it will emit its next signal to openURLSubject.
5. RemindersViewController listening to openURLSubject will perform some action since now its loaded and the signal was emitted.

   class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

   ```
   let openURLSubject = RACSubject()

   func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
       RemindersLoadedSignal.subscribeNextAs({ (loaded:NSBool) -> () in
           println("This subscription works for some reason")
       })
       return true
   }

   func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
       myTabBar.selectTabWithClass(RemindersViewController.self)

       //SendNext to openURLSubject once the tab is loaded
       RemindersLoadedSignal.subscribeNextAs({ (loaded:NSBool) -> () in
           println("This subscription Never gets called")
           self.openURLSubject.sendNext(reminderURLRequest)
       })
       return true
   }
   ```

   }

   let RemindersLoadedSignal = RACSubject()

   class RemindersViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           bindViewModel()
       }

   ```
   func bindViewModel(){
       sharedAppDelegate().openURLSubject.subscribeNextAs { (request:OpenURLRequest) -> () in
           println("got url request")
       }
       RemindersLoadedSignal.sendNext(NSBoolTrue)
   }
   ```

   }

I dont understand how the subscription in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions works and the one in application:openURL:... doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up loading the view with doNext and Zipping the signal with the RemindersLoadedSignal.

If you see any potential problems with that please let me know.

Thanks

```
.doNext { (_:AnyObject!) -> Void in
            if let myTabBar = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
                myTabBar.selectTabWithClass(RemindersViewController.self)
            }
        }
        .zipWith(RemindersLoadedSignal)
```